# SSRS Dataset data only showing 1 groups data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

My ds is displaying all the records correctly when going through the GUI but when I preview the report only one of the 2 groupings set up actually display.

There are no filters, and no visibility expressions on the tablix or the dataset.

...frustrating!

Æ

Comment: Maybe you have a tablix that only has one or more header rows, not any group header or detail rows?

Comment: Just rebuilt the tablix (seemingly exactly the same structurally) and it works now.